# Почему выдает false?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import PageOne from "./pageone";


class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      WeatherObj: null,
      trigger: false,
      mark: []
    }
  }

  change(e) {
    this.setState({
      trigger: !this.state.trigger
    });
    console.log(this.state.trigger);
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      input id = "checkBox"
      value = "bmw"
      type = "checkbox"
      onClick = {
        this.change.bind(this)
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    )



  }

}
export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Простейши реакт пример. Мы нажимаем на инпут, и меняется trigger в state. Почему когда я первый раз нажимаем на инпут, мне консоль выдает false. У меня же изначально false стоит, оно должно его изменить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и должно быть, почитай [component-lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)
Проверить можешь так

```
componentWillUpdate(props, {trigger}) {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate __', trigger )
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю связи, componentWillUpdate вызывается до render. Какая тут связь с изменением свойства state после нажатия кнопки пользователем?

Comment: Да, вызывается до рендера, но новый state уже можно посмотреть в нем, а то что показываете в функции change показывает старый

Comment: Все понял, если вынести вот сюда

Comment: render() { 
  console.log(this.state.trigger);

Comment: То нормально, спасибо